# Bootstrap's class table-hover causing a problem. Can someone help me in solving it?

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I'm have a floating reload button in my website. Also i have a table containing bootstrap's class i.e. table-hover. Now when i hover over a row, table-hover highlights that particular row (See 1st Image) but it also overlaps my floating reload button (See 2nd Image).

Image 1: 
[image: Image 1:]

Image 2: 
[image: Image 2:]

My floating button CSS:

```
.reload_button {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

What changes do i need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use z-index on floating refresh button: `z-index: 1000; // more or less depending on other element`